# Start nautilus and bring it to front

Tags: nautilus

I am using

```
nautilus -w --browser /home
```

for a shortcut command on my system. The thing is that nautilus does not get the focus after it started. Can I extend this command such that the window pops up on top of all other open windows with focus?

Comment: possible duplicate of [keyboard Shortcut for opening a new window in Ubuntu and raise it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/507953/keyboard-shortcut-for-opening-a-new-window-in-ubuntu-and-raise-it)

Comment: I edited the title of the linked question a bit, since it was not completely clearly connected to the question :). The last script my be the most useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Not many commands can achieve this without any headache. One of the successful, that I know of, is `xdotool` and even this is somewhat debatable. So you can extend the shortcut to this line:

```
nautilus -w --browser /home & xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class nautilus windowactivate
```