# Open another instance of current directory in Nautilus

Tags: scripts, nautilus, directory, filemanager, nautilus-script

In `Microsoft Windows`, when you are open File Explorer at a specific path, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to open another file explorer in the same path. But in Ubuntu when I try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> it opens Home Folder. How I can duplicate the same file browser window? (I use Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: You can use right click menu by hovering on the tab - Open in a New Window.

Comment: Perhaps this might help: http://askubuntu.com/q/507953/57576

Comment: `thunar` file browser provide such option with same shortcut (installed by default for Xubuntu) I expect you are looking for the feature with Ubuntu/Unity/Nautilus, right?

Comment: @user.dz I tested `thunar` and it was that. But I thought I can add that functionality to native file browser. Do you have any Idea in about that?

Comment: @JacobVlijm OK! Thank you for your efforts ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using right-click on any of the files in the directory instead of a keyboard shortcut, it can be done easily.

#### How to setup

1. Create, if it doesn't exist yet, the directory `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`
2. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `new_window_here` (no extension in `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`, and ***Make the script executable***
3. Log out and back in. That's it. Now whenever you right-click on (any) file in a directory, choose <kbd>Scripts</kbd> > <kbd>new_window_here</kbd>, another window pops up in the same directory:

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os

def replace(path):
    for c in [("%23", "#"), ("%5D", "]"), ("%5E", "^"),
              ("file://", ""), ("%20", " ")]:
        path = path.replace(c[0], c[1])
    return path

def get(command):
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(command).decode("utf-8").strip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

# get the current path
current = replace(os.getenv("NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI"))
dr = os.path.realpath(current)
# call the window
subprocess.call(["nautilus", "--new-window", dr])
```

*Right-click any file > <kbd>Scripts</kbd> > <kbd>new_window_here</kbd>*

[image]

*...to open a new nautilus window in the same directory.*

[image]

Comment: @hasanghaforian great! You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

- Another option: (Shortcut+Drag)

  1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open new tab in same folder
  2. Drag it out

  [image]
- Still another way: (2 Clicks)

  In the header bar: Right Click on current folder → Open in New Window

Comment: Thank you! I did not know we can open tabs in `nautilus`!

Comment: @hasanghaforian, so you are windows user generally? Most programs that opened much provide tabs, most file/web browsers, terminal emulators, remote clients (rdp, vnc ssh...), text editors ... I added another way (two clicks)